# Jailbreak IOS 10.0.1 device via mach_portal without unlocking the iDevice

Tags: iphone, ios, security, jailbreak

Is there a way to jailbreak an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.0.1 via mach_portal (a basic root shell exploit which can be found [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=965)) while the device is locked, maybe some runtime code injection exploit etc. , or is the whole NAND encrypted while the device is locked?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to jailbreak an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.0.1 via mach_portal (a basic root shell exploit which can be found here) while the device is locked?

No. The `mach_portal` exploit requires you to install and run an application on the device, which requires the device to be unlocked.

Additionally, the `mach_portal` exploit is not a jailbreak. It could potentially be *one component* of a jailbreak, but it would need to be combined with a number of other important components (e.g, kernel patches to disable code signature checks and sandboxing) to allow it to be used as one.

> … or is the whole NAND encrypted while the device is locked?

It's complicated. All storage on iOS devices is encrypted. However, some of this data is encrypted using only a key that's embedded into the processor (the device UID), making it accessible at all times; other data is encrypted using a key that is wrapped using the device's passcode, making it only available when the device is unlocked.

Some details on this system are available in Apple's [iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf). But the TL;DR is that most of the important data is inaccessible until the device is unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

From an interesting [article](https://www.darthnull.org/2014/10/06/ios-encryption) about iOS security:

> 1. Since the iPhone 3GS, all iOS devices have used a hardware-based AES full-disk encryption that prevents storage from being moved from
>      one device to another, and facilitates a fast wipe of the disk.
> 2. Since iOS 4 (iPhone 4), additional protections have been available using the Data Protection API (DPAPI).
> 3. The DPAPI allows files to be flagged such that they are always encrypted when the device is locked, or encrypted after reboot (but
>      not encrypted after the user enters their passcode once).
> 4. Once a user locks a device with a passcode, the class keys for “complete” encryption are wiped from memory, and so that data is unreadable, even when booting from a trusted external image.
> 5. Once a user reboots a device, the “complete until first
>      authentication” keys are lost from memory, and any files under that
> 6. DPAPI protection level will be unreadable even when booted from an
>      external image. Under iOS 8, many built-in applications received the
>      “complete until first authentication” protection.

Comment: Is it possible to install mach_portal as a demo bundle via DCSD thus enabling it to be run on a locked iDevice? (doc can be found here: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DCSD )